# How to connect PostgreSQL database from flutter?

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, dart

I want to connect PostgreSQL to my flutter application as my database for it. Is shelf package relevant or should I make API for the same.
Please tell, I am finding solutions from many days but today I got to know about the shelf dart package. Is it enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, PostgreSQL DB already has a dependency in the [Pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/postgres), you can use it to access the database but of course, the database should be hosted in **Cloud** or **Localhost** for development then you can use it easily with this dependency, or if you'd like to create an API that's totally acceptable.

Comment: Thanks so much sir. I know Postgres dependency but actually I dont want to use any external thing to access my database and their developers is also not known. So can you please tell which language can be used to make API?

Comment: You're welcome my friend , actually any language can make you an API but the best is JavaScript or TypeScript with NodeJS or NestJS, PHP, C#, Java, Golang & Python, personally I recommend ASP.NET Core WEB API with C# you'll take very amazing performance as well as features from a high-level language.

Comment: again thank you sir....can you please resolve my one more query....do I need to host my postgre database in cloud at developmental level and also how to connect that api with my app and database?

Comment: You're welcome anytime my friend , first you don't need to host your DB in the cloud at the development phase you can just install it in your computer and use it as a localhost server, and for connect your DB with your API just pick one framework to use and search in YouTube you'll find many courses on how to do that, after you develop your API you can use the DTO dependency on pub.dev for connecting your API into your application and interacting with, also you don't need to host your API in the cloud in the development phase, & that's it please mark my answer as the right now if it helps 

Comment: OK Sir.... I have downloaded visual studio for creating ASP .NET Web API...

Comment: Sir what is DTO dependency.... I can't find it on pub.dev

Comment: Sorry my bad, I mean DIO you can find it here - https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Comment: sir how will I get my api address?

Comment: If you mean locally, you can add it like this http://localhost or like this http://your_pc_ip_address:your_api_port_number

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your Flutter application to an already set up and hosted PostgreSQL database, using the Postgres package.

First of all, set up a PostgreSQL database, and host it either locally or over the cloud.

In your Flutter project, add the Postgres package as a dependency in your.yaml file and also import it.

Create an API by connecting using this package. You can use this API to query the database further.

Comment: Thanks...can you please tell how my app will be connected to may api?