# Flutter Web Application project connecting to a Postgresql database template

Tags: postgresql, flutter

A project I got involved in was `a Survey mobile app` that will have `a Web Administration site` for the questions, **respondents and answers management/dashboard**. It was decided that I should use `Flutter` to just have one `programming language` and use `PostgreSQL` for **the database**. This is my first time to use `Flutter` and have check some `YouTube tutorials`.  However most of them are outdated, the [postgres library](https://pub.dev/packages/postgres) is currently **version 3.0.6**, and the `PostgreSQLConnection` is **deprecated** which was used in the tutorials.  I have sought some answers using **Microsoft Bing** which uses **ChatGPT** but its answers are also outdated. I have tried to "update" the code it generated with my limited understanding and it did not work.
I have previously worked on **a MERN project** and used **data models** and **controllers** for better organization and here is what I have initially for the folder structure from Bing's recommendation:

```
-- /lib
   |-- main.dart
   |-- /models
       |-- user.dart
   |-- /services
       |-- database.dart
       |-- userservice.dart
   |-- /pages
       |-- login_page.dart
       |-- admin_page.dart
```

user.dart

```
class User {
  final int userId;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String name;
  final String accountType;


  User({
    required this.userId,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.name,
    required this.accountType,

  });
}
```

database.dart

```
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

class Database {
  static final Database _singleton = Database._internal();

  factory Database() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  Database._internal();

  final Endpoint _endpoint = Endpoint(
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'xxx_db',
    username: 'xxx_admin',
    password: 'xxx',
  );

  get connection {
    return _endpoint;
  }

  Future<void> openConnection() async {
    await Connection.open(_endpoint);
  }

  Future<void> closeConnection() async {
    await connection.close();
  }
}
```

user_service.dart

```
import 'package:webadmin/models/user.dart';
import 'database.dart';

class UserService {
  final _database = Database();

  Future<User?> login(String email, String password) async {
    await _database.openConnection();

    var result = await _database.connection.execute(
        "SELECT * from survey.users WHERE email=@email AND password = crypt(@password,password)");

    await _database.closeConnection();

    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      return User(
          userId: result[0][0],
          email: result[0][1],
          password: result[0][2],
          name: result[0][3],
          accountType: result[0][4]);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The `database.dart` was modified from an answer from Bing that used a deprecated `PostgreSQLConnection` so I modified.  I planned to use this library for connecting to services. Right now, the `User Service` is existing, but I will create later like `QuestionsService`, `RespondentService`, etc.  I know both the `database.dart` and `user_service.dart` is incorrect since I have tried to run this and got the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported operation: Socket constructor
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:294:3)
    at Socket._connect (io_patch.dart:489:5)
    at Socket.connect (socket.dart:758:21)
    at _connect (connection.dart:234:31)
    at _connect.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:127:5)
    at PgConnectionImplementation._connect (connection.dart:227:49)
    at connect (connection.dart:200:25)
    at connect.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:127:5)
    at PgConnectionImplementation.connect (connection.dart:193:52)
    at Connection.open (postgres.dart:210:39)
    at database.Database._internal.openConnection (database.dart:24:22)
    at openConnection.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:127:5)
    at database.Database._internal.openConnection (database.dart:23:30)
    at user_service.UserService.new.login (user_service.dart:8:21)
    at login.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
  ...
```

My question is what should be **the recommended approach/way to connect to a POSTGRESQL database**? Can someone fix `database.dart` and `user_service.dart` to make the Login function work?

I have search for answers and tutorials about this but most answers are the old way, using `PostgreSQLConnection` which is deprecated.  Microsoft Bing is not helpful since in its own admission, its last data mine was in the year 2021.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you somehow want a flutter web app (on the public internet I presume) to directly access the postgresql server. **Don't** do this.

Instead you should be looking at a cloud-function server somewhere that can provide a RESTful API after appropriate authentication, and can use whatever native language works there to talk to your postgres database.

Having said that, [Supabase](https://supabase.com/) has postgres at its core, and has many pub packages to connect directly with flutter mobile, desktop, and web.

Comment: Why should I not do it this way? There is related question here ins stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76693729/how-to-connect-postgresql-database-from-flutter but unfortunately it did not show any code for me to check.  I cannot use Supabase since it is a paid service.

Comment: Supabase software is all open source.  They even give you docker build instructions.  You pay only when you want them to host for you and use their scaling.  And like firebase, there's a free tier that you might not even exceed.

Comment: I have installed Supabase by [self-hosting with Docker](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/self-hosting/docker).  I have configured and have accessed the dashboard.  Question though, how can I create a new project/database? It seems I can only add tables? Does that mean I need to have 1 Supabase docker container for each database/project?

Comment: An instance of postgres can certainly hold multiple databases.  I'm not sure how that is reflected in the supabase client API, but postgres can do it.